# How to use 'as' props (elementType) in react-bootstrap Components?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

In react-bootstrap documentation, there is 'as' props in API of every component with Type elementType. 
I can't figure out how to use it in component. I tried passing in React components and `"<div>test</div>"` as "as" props but didn't work. I tried to search for any example or implementation but could not find any. Thanks.

Comment: you need to tell it what element to use, not how the element should display. `as="div"`

Comment: Thanks! Now the description makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing component type that will be instantiated with JSX. Internally it looks something alike

```
function Button(props) {
 const ComponentType = as;
 .......
  <ComponentType ......>
```

So as you know it will work if it's a string with tagname of native element(`"div"`, `"table"` etc) or valid React component(class inherited `React.Component` or function for functional component)

Answer (score 1):

I needed this to customize the tab of a nav component

```
     <Nav className='tabs-div' variant='tabs' >
        <Nav.Item  >
          <Nav.Link className='pending'  eventKey={-1}>Pending</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link className='positive' eventKey={1}>Positive</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link className='negative' eventKey={0}>Negative</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
```

you can understand from the code that the tab will be as normal.
but I needed another costumization with notification on the tab icons ....

so I created a component like this

```
import React from 'react'

class BtnPending extends React.Component{


    render(){
        return(
            <button className='btn btn-warning' >Pending</button> // this is just for the sake of demo
        )
    }
}


export default BtnPending;
```

Nav.Link will be changed to this

```
<Nav.Link as={()=>{return(<BtnPending/>)}} eventKey={-1}>Pending</Nav.Link>
```

for Tab in react-bootstrap you can also use the argument title